# Windows Azure Mobile Service POST request getting cut off

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

We're recieving big XML structures in form of a POST request to our Azure Mobile Service API.

In that regard, we have an issue where the XML is cut off halfway because of some unknown cause.
Is there some sort of limit to how large a request can be to Azure Mobile Services?

Edit: Update on the sizes of the XML that is sent... It's no more than 3 kilobytes, usually. Which makes me believe there is something really wrong somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

This is strange ... I'm easily able to send huge objects (several MB) as POST parameter to WAMS.
Can you provide some more Details, e.g. the object type.
If the type is XML, provide/ check the config of XML Serializer.

Comment: I'm sorry, actually. It turned out the error was happening a bit higher up than that.

The XML that was sent from the customer was actually malformed! I had to consult them about it and it all turned out OK.

Thanks for your answer, though.